# Where is Twisted.pair?

Tags: python, network-programming, twisted

I have tried this both with Python 2.7 and Python 3.3.

[The Twisted Documentation](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.pair.html) says that in the current version, **pair** is part of the API.  However, trying to import it.  Using, for example, `from twisted.pair import *` fails.  Searching with pip shows no results.  How can I use **twisted.pair**?

**Update**

Here are the steps I took to install Twisted and everything else for my project, on Fedora 20:

```
  # yum install python-pip
  # pip install pytun
  # yum install gcc
  # yum install twisted
  # pip install autobahn
```

I also tried to run everything with Python-3, but that also gave me problems (most notably, pip-python3 wouldn't install pytun.)

Here's the top of my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import pytun
import logging
from iniparse import INIConfig
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor
from twisted.python import log
from twisted.protocols.loopback import loopbackTCP
from twisted.internet.interfaces import IReadDescriptor
from twisted.internet.interfaces import IFileDescriptor
from twisted.pair import *
from autobahn.twisted.websocket import WebSocketServerFactory
from autobahn.twisted.websocket import WebSocketServerProtocol
from autobahn.twisted.websocket import WebSocketClientFactory
from autobahn.twisted.websocket import WebSocketClientProtocol
from autobahn.twisted.websocket import listenWS
```

And here's what happens when I try to run it:

```
    from twisted.pair import *
ImportError: No module named pair
```

**Update**

While Fedora's Twisted package does not have pair, pip's still does.  So I'm using pip's Twisted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from twisted.pair import *
```

works fine for me on my machine.  You will need to include the details of how you installed twisted, where you downloaded it from, what exact operating system you are using, and so on.